# Numerically stable and efficient way to compute matrix $Z$ such that $e^Z=e^Xe^Y$

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

Is there a known way to calculate matrix $Z$ such that $e^Z=e^Xe^Y$ in an efficient and numerically stable way? $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices and can be complex.

Naively computing it is numerically unstable as the matrix exponential can easily get overflow or underflow.
Another alternative is to use BCH formula. However, the series in BCH formula might be slow to converge (and I’m not even sure if the convergence is guaranteed for all matrices).

Comment: Not even remotely an expert, but out of general curiosity I searched "numerically stable Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff" and found [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2656) which seems relevant!

Comment: @prets, the paper shows a method to compute the BCH, but doesn't address the fundamental limitations of BCH (i.e. non-convergence on some cases)

Comment: Please excuse my very ignorant question, but why doesn't $Z=X+Y$ work?

Comment: No, it doesn't work necessarily when $X$ and $Y$ don't commutate.

Comment: Short answer because $X$ and $Y$ might not be commutative, i.e. $XY$ might not be equal to $YX$.
If $Z = X + Y$, this means that $e^X e^Y = e^{X + Y} = e^{Y + X} = e^Y e^X$, the left term and the right term only equals if $e^X$ and $e^Y$ are commutative, while we know that might not be true in all cases.

Comment: The slight problem is that even for one dimensional matrices, the $Z$ is not uniquely determined. Which of the many values of $Z$ do you expect to compute?

Comment: Perhaps some information of the dimension of $X$ and $Y$ can help. Is there any bound to it?

Comment: @Somos what do you mean by one dimensional matrices?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz, the only information is that $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices (the requirement to be able to compute the matrix exponential). Other than that, there is no bound to their sizes.

Comment: @Firman I meant $1\times 1$ matrices are just the same as numbers. So $e^z = e^x e^y = e^{x+y}$ does not determine $z$ uniquely.

Comment: @Somos any $Z$ is fine for me.

Comment: One obvious possibility is to compute $Z(t)$ such that $e^{Z(t)}=e^{tX}e^Y$ ($t\in [0,1]$) using truncated BCH and going in small steps in $t$ (so $Z(t+dt)$ is computed from $Z(t)$ and $(dt)X$). That is like solving an ODE with something like Runge-Kutta and you can easily develop an iterative scheme of arbitrarily high order of precision in terms of the step. However I don't know if it is efficient enough for you.

Comment: Maybe the [Split-Step Fourier Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-step_method) could help?

Comment: I think, in my unprofessional opinion, that you would have to specify your level of efficiency or error. In order to calculate $Z$ you could consider the power series representation of  $Z=\log(\exp(X)\exp(Y))$ and only then truncate with sufficient margin of error. This error would be intimately connected with the efficiency required.